# Mysql Like Offset Limit Query not working

Tags: mysql, sql

When I try this query I got not results :

```
SELECT * FROM m_blog 
WHERE isdeleted='0' and title LIKE '%t%' 
ORDER by createdAt DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

But when I use this query I got correct results :

```
SELECT * FROM m_blog 
WHERE isdeleted='0' and title LIKE '%t%' 
ORDER by createdAt DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I thought the reason is **`LIKE`** condition with **`OFFSET`** not working but why? and how can I use this query ?

Comment: ..according to definition of `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, it is clear that it will yield an empty result ... with `LIMIT N` (show only first N rows) and `OFFSET N` (show all results where row_id > N) ... :)

Comment: ..there can be no (singe) "row_id" which meets the condition `row_id <= N AND row_id > N`...

Comment: so `OFFSET M` makes only sense in combination with `LIMIT N`, when `M < N`! (and would get you the `M+1`th to `N`th row ..from the (original) result set)

Comment: what is it that you are trying to achieve with the OFFSET? what records do you want to see if there aren't more than 10?

Comment: i want to list some records using offset

Comment: then ensure: offset is lower than limit ..and offset is lower than the total count of rows.

Comment: i can't get you please give me a sample

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You have no rows where this condition is true:

```
isdeleted = '0' and title LIKE '%t%'
```

You do have rows where this condition is true:

```
content LIKE '%a%'
```

Note that the `isdeleted` is not applied to this condition.

This has nothing to do with using `like and`limit`.

Comment: check second query that query had results

Answer (score 0):

The `OFFSET N` option will move the starting pointer to the Nth position and start returning rows from there onwards, ordered by the `ORDER BY`.

Your first query isn't retrieving rows because there aren't more than 10 rows (as max) to retrieve. So when you are telling the engine "bring me the 11th onward" and there are only 5 rows, it returns nothing.

Remove the `OFFSET` to see the data, or conditionally apply it once the data is retrieved into a temp table.

Comment: so i can't query this condition ?

Comment: @gowtham : if the query returns only two results, imagine it return an array with element 0 and 1. Now the same query with `offset 10` try to get data from the same array but the first element should be 10...you have only element 0 and 1, so it won't return anything since you have no element starting at 10. Hope you understand it?

Comment: but after sometime it return more than 10 then how can i query that ?